# How to set some value to zero in a specific interval

Tags: python

Recently I have some problem about how to set some value to zero
here is my code:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
b=[]
c=[]
e=[]
for st in range(0,10):
    b.append(a[st])
    if (b>5) or (b<3):
        c=b
    else:
        c=0
    e=c
print e
```

I hope the result is to be `e=[1,2,0,0,0,6,7,8,9,10]`, but the result of `e` is always not what I want.I use another way I found on this website `b[ma.logical_or(b<5,b>3)]=0`,it still doesn't have any great result I want.Does anybody help me to solve the question?

Comment: Looks like you need to watch a quick video about how assignments and names in Python work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Comment: You are doing many redundant operations here. I'd recommend using slice assignment for it is more convenient, but to correct your code would be to practically rewrite it.

Comment: One more thing: Perhaps try and upload the code with detailed comments about what you're doing at each step (And why)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing and slice assignment:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
a[2:5] = [0, 0, 0]
a[:10]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Extra pythonic: `a[2:5] = [0] * 3`

Comment: Or even `a[2:5] = [0] * (5 - 2)` :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

but,'a' is a hypothetical set.In fact, i want import the set from excel,so there are so many data to process.I think the method with "if...else..." is better.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` can be randomly ordered, a simple list comprehension will do the trick.

```
>>> a
[12, 14, 4, 2, 7, 3, 13, 5, 6, 1, 10, 9, 8, 15, 11]
>>> [0 if 3 <= x <= 5 else x for x in a]
[12, 14, 0, 2, 7, 0, 13, 0, 6, 1, 10, 9, 8, 15, 11]
```

However, at your level a straight up for loop might be more educational.

```
>>> result = []
>>> for x in a:
...     if 3 <= x <= 5:
...         result.append(0)
...     else:
...         result.append(x)
... 
>>> result
[12, 14, 0, 2, 7, 0, 13, 0, 6, 1, 10, 9, 8, 15, 11]
```

I still recommend that you watch the video I linked you in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will watch the video to clarify the problem.